# Need Bootstrap's " table table-hover" to allow for highlighting white all row text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table that utilizes Bootstrap's "table" and "table-hover" classes

Inside each identical table row is the following:

- Thumbnail
- Heading (H5) which must be black colored text
- 3 pieces of text (span) elements, indented from the heading, which must be grey colored text
- A Download button pulled to the right (actually a font awesome icon). Also must be a grey icon and grey colored text

The desired result is that when hovering the row (anywhere inside row), all the text (heading, spans, font awesome icon and download link) turn the text color white and the row background blue.

Thus far I have managed to make the background blue all turn white except for the heading.

I was really hoping the CSS :not() selector would do the trick, but no such luck.

I am a newbie, so have probably gone about it the wrong way.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

You can see the approach I took on this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willrichardson/4vLkcb6k/2/)

The HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <div class="col-sm-10" id="Table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <!-- <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead> -->

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;>
                            <div id="searchResultHeading">                          
                                <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
                            </div>                      
                                <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> <br>
                                <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                            <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                                <a href="#"> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



</body>
```

The CSS

```
    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
a {
    color: #22c7fa;
}
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td:hover {
    background-color: #22c7fa;
    color: #fff;
}
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td > i {
    color: #inherit;
}
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td > div > a {
    color: inherit;
}

#table > table {
    margin-left: 97px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
/*Make all text in the search results grey*/
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    color: #919191;
}
/*Make the headings in the search results black*/
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h5{
    color:#323333;
}
/*Make all text in the search results turn white on hover*/
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td:hover {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Indent the search results details */
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td > span {
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `:hover` selector isn't specific enough to override the `h5` styling:

```
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h5{
    color:#323333;
}
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td:hover h5 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vLkcb6k/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a closing quote on your image tag:

```
<img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;>
```

If you add that in, it works correctly.

```css
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    a {
      color: #22c7fa;
    }
    .table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td:hover {
      background-color: #22c7fa;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td > div > a {
      color: inherit;
    }
    #table > table {
      margin-left: 97px;
      margin-right: 60px;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    /*Make all text in the search results grey*/
    #Table > table > tbody > tr > td {
      padding-left: 0px;
      color: #919191;
    }
    /*Make the headings in the search results black*/
    #Table > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h5 {
      color: #323333;
    }
    /*Make all text in the search results turn white on hover*/
    #Table > table > tbody > tr > td:hover {
      padding-left: 0px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    /* Indent the search results details */
    #Table > table > tbody > tr > td > span {
      padding-left: 6px;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

  <div class="col-sm-10" id="Table">
    <table class="table table-hover">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
              <div id="searchResultHeading">
                <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
              </div>
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> 
              <br>
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
              <div id="searchResultHeading">
                <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
              </div>
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> 
              <br>
              <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: thanks for getting in touch so quickily and catching my typo.  That did in indeed get me close to where I needed to be. I  really appreciate it.  Ultimately the CSS provided by uʍopǝpısdn produced the behavior I was looking for.   Thanks again!